# How can I resolve FormBuilder inside a service (Symfony4)?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, service, formbuilder

I try to create a Form in my Service:

```
namespace App\Service;


class FormGenerator
{

public function createForm($slug,$request)
  {

    $item = new $EntityName();
    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($item);

    ....
```

But I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createFormBuilder" of
>   class "App\Service\FormGenerator".

Comment: This is your 4th question in two days about actually the same 'problem': not understanding how services work. They have a negative score for a good reason. As I said before: read the documentation! This is a really basic question if you're working with Symfony. Based on your reputation, you should know better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form builder instance is present in the `AbstractController` (Where most of the controllers extend it). So that's why you are able to use `$this->createFormBuilder()`. But in this case, you have created a separate service so you need to resolve the form builder yourself.

I'm not sure about how you would do it in Symfony but according to the documentation and [this link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-forms/the-form-type-class) you can typehint the form builder class and you will get the instance in your method. something like below

The code has been updated to import the FormBuilderInterface via constructor injection

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class FormGenerator 
{
   private $builder;

   public function __construct(FormBuilderInterface $builder) {
      $this->builder = $builder;
   }

   public function createForm($slug,$request)
   {
     $this->builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('speciesCount')
            ->add('funFact')
   }
}
```

Then you will have to resolve this class (`FormGenerator`) via DI into your logic of choice preferably by type-hinting it in the constructor of the subscriber of this service class. Hope it makes a little more sense

Comment: While this is upvoted and even accepted, this does not answer the question. Auto-injection by Typehinting only works in controller methods (Actions), while this question is about using a service (`FormBuilderInterface`) in a service (`App\Service\FormGenerator`).

Comment: I think you are partially true in this case. because autoinjection works for any class that you create under the `src/` directory. But not necessary for all the methods. if you typehint it in the constructor of the service class, then you will that dependency will be autoinjected (If my memory is correct I have done it this way in the past). I will update the answer with neccessary code if you can confirm :)

Comment: Actaully I went ahead and updated the answer, If you would mind taking a look, I'd appreciate it, symfony noob please

Answer (score 1):

As explained in previous answer, the form builder instance is present in the AbstractController that most controllers extend.

But, if you want to use this FormBuilder in a Service (which has few use cases, but can be done), I recommend you to use the FormFactory service.

Here is a example :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

class MyService
{
    protected $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory) {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function getMyForms(): array
    {
        return [
            'deleteForm' => $this->formFactory->create()
                            ->addAction(…)->setMethod('DELETE')
                            ->getForm(),
            
            'addForm' => $this->formFactory->create()
                            ->addAction(…)
                            ->getForm(),
            /* etc… */
        ];
    }
}
```